# Morphia Complex Mongodb Aggregate ($substr, $project, $sort, etc...)

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using Java's Morphia library.

Via the command line client I was able to successfully execute the following aggregate

```
db.shows.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        _id: 1,
        title: 1
    }},
    {$group:
        {
            _id: {titleLetter: {$substr: ["$title", 0, 1]}},
            count: {$sum: 1},
            shows: {$push: "$title"}
        }
    },
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
]);
```

Which gives me a list of shows group by the first letter of the show's title.

On the official [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/guides/querying/) for morphia I see they can take in a `DBObject` for `AdvancedDatastore.createQuery` but I don't see anything similar for aggregates.

Perhaps i would use something like

```
BasicDBObject parse = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse("{$group: { _id: {titleLetter: {$substr: [\"$title\", 0, 1]}}, count: {$sum: 1}, shows: {$push: \"$title\"} } }");
```

Similarly there is the `BasicDBObjectBuilder` approach

```
DBObject group = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().push("$group")
        .add("_id", "{titleLetter: {$substr: [\"$title\", 0, 1]}}")
        .get();
```

So i can convert the CLI query to something Morphia or at least something from `import com.mongodb.*;` to something that Java understands.

I have not been able to get this query to run from Java using any method.

My question is what is a clean approach to converting my aggregate query in the cli to a query in Java and which would eventually return a Java object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `Input`, `Output` and `Main` class like below.

Main class creates Morphia equivalent of Cli query and provides the input and output class.

Morphia takes care of validating & mapping mongo data to and from request and response.

Input Class

```
package org.mongodb.morphia;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity("Input")
public class Input implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String title;
  //Getters and Setters
}
```

Output Class

```
package org.mongodb.morphia;
import java.util.List;
public class Output {
    private int count;
    private List<String> shows;
 //Getters and Setters
}
```

Main Class

```
package org.mongodb.morphia;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.AggregationPipeline;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import static org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Accumulator.accumulator;
import static org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Group.*;
import static org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Projection.projection;
import static org.mongodb.morphia.query.Sort.descending;

public class MorphiaClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
        morphia.mapPackage("org.mongodb.morphia");
        final Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "test");
        AggregationPipeline pipeline = datastore.createAggregation(Input.class).
                project(projection("id"), projection("title")).
                group(id(grouping("titleLetter", accumulator("$substr", Arrays.asList("$title", 0, 1)))),
                        grouping("count", accumulator("$sum", 1)),
                        grouping("shows", accumulator("$push", "title"))).
                sort(descending("id"));
        List<Output> results = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Output> iterator = pipeline.aggregate(Output.class);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            results.add(iterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This an excellent and clear answer. Using the pipeline like this is just as easy to read as the JSON and its easier to write. Thanks